# put the data from an api link using this function and console.log it

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I want to use a variable which has the JSON data to later parse and stringify it

All I want now is to see the actual array of objects in the console!

```
console.log(fetchJSON('url'));

function fetchJSON(url, cb) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = () => {
      if (xhr.status < 400) {
        cb(null, xhr.response);
      } else {
        cb(new Error(`Network error: ${xhr.status} - ${xhr.statusText}`));
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = () => cb(new Error('Network request failed'));
    xhr.send();
  }
```

I expect the output of `console.log(fetchJSON('url'));`
to be `<the array of objects from the link>`.

Comment: What is the second parameter cb supposed to be?

Comment: You are not passing a callback function, so this doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fetchJSON('url', function(result) {

console.log(result);

});
```

Your function fetchJSON is returning a callback function. If you want to return just the result change

this

```
cb(null, xhr.response);
```

to:

```
return xhr.response;
```